# PHP: What to use for email confirmation code?

Tags: php, decode

I first tried `base64` to encode `mail@domain.com` but it includes `/` which breaks my URL which is as `http://example.com/verify/<confirmation_code>`

I don't want to store in Db, I want on the fly process,provided I can pass my own Salt. What should I use?

Comment: If the problem is the encoding, you can try something else like SHA-1

Comment: Anything you like could work if [__`urlencode()`__](http://php.net/urlencode) is used. You'll have to decode that of course on the handling the code. Also I'm not sure why do you need encrypting and not hash. I.e. why it has to be two-ways

Comment: @AlmaDo I am sending an email with generated code appended in URL, something like this `http://example.com/verify/<code>. If it contains a `/` it breaks thing up

Answer (score 0):

You can encode user id and send it as your confirmation code from where you can check that id.

Comment: How sending an ID in a `base64` could make sure it will *NOT* contain `/` in it?

Comment: you can use md5 also for encryption.

Comment: `md5` is 1-way hashing.

Comment: yes it is but you can process with query in PHP side and get your result what you want?

Comment: I am not storing md5 based data. Or you may elaborate it

Comment: so you can take user id as base64 encoded string and send it.

Comment: Read the Question again. Thanks

Comment: based on user id you can validate the email id of that user.

Comment: if you encode mail@domain.com as base64 then it will gives you bWFpbEBkb21haW4uY29t can you tell me where is "/" ?

Comment: You can't be sure it will not contain a `/` `mail@domain` is just an example. `base64` includes a `/` too

Comment: Base64 implementation uses A-Z, a-z, and 0-9 for the first 62 values

Comment: you can read it on that site, and please give me any email that contain "/"

Comment: do one thing first encrypt with base64 and then do urlencode, so then never chance of / in the string.

Answer (score 0):

I use base_64 for encoding image inks to send to a resizing script this is 1 of the encryptions...

aHR0cDovLzEyM3N0b3Jlcy5jb20vbWVkaWEvY2F0YWxvZy9wcm9kdWN0L2svby9rb29sYXRyb25vbmxpbmVfMjIyMV84OTIwMTk2LmpwZw==

there is no slashes in base_64... are you using  base64_encode to encrypt and  base64_decode to decrypt?